# Find minimum and maximum numbers of Math.sin()

Tags: javascript

Imagine that there is a pendulum swinging from -1 to 1:

[image]

This pendulum is equivalent to SINE. Imagine also that this pendulum is swinging quite fast in an update loop of 60fps.

This might be my code:

```
let angle = 0

function update() {
    angle += .1

    pendulum.angle = Math.sin(angle)

    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

update()
```

That's all fine. What I want is to detect the point at which this pendulum is closest to -1 or 1. One may think you could just write:

```
if (pendulum.angle == -1 || pendulum.angle == 1) {
    console.log('pendulum is at it\'s maximum')
}
```

However, it doesn't quite work like that: If the pendulum's speed was moving quite fast, it may miss -1 or 1 completely!
Another seemingly possible solution is to detect if the pendulum is within a certain range and if so, raise the message:

```
if (pendulum.angle < -0.9 || pendulum.angle > 0.9) {
    console.log('pendulum is at it\'s maximum')
}
```

...But what if the speed was going really, really fast? What if it missed *those* ranges?

The angle's getting bigger is being restricted to the programs framerate - so the faster it spins, the more space it skips.

This leads to the question: *What formula could I use to find out how large the range should be - based on it's speed?*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because the speed variable seems not relevant. Sin is always going to be between -1 and 1, and that will be set based on the number passed in, which is increasing at a "constant" rate. I put constant in quotes because it's not quite true, it increasres by 0.1 which is constant, but requestAnimationFrame runs at the users refresh rate, which is variable. So...are you trying to account for faster refresh rates? Do you want your pendulum to swing faster on higher refresh rate screens?

Comment: I will edit it and make it clearer

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you correctly, but there are a well defined set of values where `sin(x) == 1` (ie x = 0.5pi, 2.5pi, 4.5pi ...) and `sin(x) == -1` (ie x = 1.5pi, 3.5pi, 5.5pi ...)

Comment: For an arbitrary function, you can perform some hysteresis.  One simple way is to compute the derivative and watch for it to change sign.  Or discretely:  `currentDiff = (currentValue - lastValue)`  then check `lastDiff * currentDiff <= 0`  Essentially when the direction of motion changes, you've reached a local maximum or minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the current value's `sin` as well as that of the preceding and subsequent values. If your `sin` value is closer to `-1` or `1` than that of the preceding *and* subsequent values, you're the closest, do your logging.

```
function update() {
    lastanglemag = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle));  // Get the preadjustment magnitude

    angle += .1

    pendulum.angle = Math.sin(angle)

    currentanglemag = Math.abs(pendulum.angle)  // Get current magnitude

    // If current magnitude is larger than both neighbors, we're at a maximum
    if (currentanglemag > lastanglemag && currentanglemag > Math.abs(Math.sin(angle + 0.1))) {
        console.log("pendulum is at its maximum")
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

update()
```

Optimizations to only compute one new `sin` per `update` (the one for the *next* `angle`), caching the other values, to reduce 2-3 `sin` calls per `update` to just one are left as an exercise for the reader (I didn't want to introduce any additional persistent state and the associated complexity, and in practice, for anything based on a GUI, the cost of 1-2 extra `sin` computations is meaningless; the user can't see a delay measured in nanoseconds anyway).

Comment: Note that you are just working your way around derivation here, but `sin()` has an easy derivative: `cos()`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help - it all makes sence to me now. Fundamentally put, **if sign changes direction, it has gone past the 1/-1 mark.**

Comment: @Joachim: Not the sign, but the sequence of values (at the maximum, all three values would be negative or positive, a switch from negative to positive or vice-versa only occurs when you're *far* from the maximum). The trick is knowing when the sequence of values has changed direction, *and* only acting on this if the current value is the one in the closest position. For a simplified example, if the sequence was just incrementing by 0.5 "rebounding" at 1, then `0.92, 0.97, 0.98` includes a change of direction, but it looks like it's still increasing.

Comment: Conveniently though, by checking before and after, we don't care; the direction changed, but `0.98` is definitionally going to be closer, and on the next pass, comparing `0.97, 0.98, 0.93` we'd see that we'd hit the maximum with `0.98`.

Comment: @tevemadar: Imma be honest here: I hate all things geometry and trig-related (and dislike, but do not truly hate, calculus). The decimal point is a tool of the devil and I do as little as possible with it (discrete math and linear algebra/number theory stuff based on integer groups is more my speed). If there's a more efficient solution way to arrive at this result, please tell me, but I've excised the part of my brain that deals with trigonometric functions and don't want to regrow it. :-)

Comment: @Joachim if the sign of `cos()` changes, that's when `sin()` "turned back".

Comment: @tevemadar: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that doesn't really help optimize much, if anything, right? Because knowing the sign changed or will change before or after the current value requires just as many `cos` computations as this requires `sin` computations (to check if the change occurs adjacent to the current value), and even once you know it changed, you'd still need to compute the `sin` values on either side of the change to know which one was closer (you can't wait until after the change, because the output must occur when you reach the closest value, not when you pass the max).

Comment: Nitpicking my own comment: I meant to say "if the sequence was just incrementing by 0.05 "rebounding" at 1", and accidentally typed "0.5" instead of "0.05". Didn't notice 'til edit window had elapsed. Boo.

Comment: @Joachim: Just a heads up, I overcomplicated the original code with all that subtracting from `1` nonsense; updated code replaced it with simple magnitude computation and comparison (removes all the `1 - ` parts and flips the tests from `<` to `>`, and I changed names and comments to match).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thank you so much! This has been a big help for me and everything works perfectly. Your new update is much simpler and easier to usderstand, which I'm sure I will keep coming back to, as I have come across this problem many times.

Comment: I think it's simpler, see other answer.

Comment: @tevemadar: Yeah, it's simpler if you discard the need to know when you're closest in favor of simply knowing when you've passed the maximum point. If you need to know when you're *closest* to the maximum point at the time you reach it that closest point, pretty sure it remains at least as complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Using that d/dx sin(x) = cos(x), one could simplify the other answer to

```
function update() {
    lastangle_d = Math.cos(angle);     // Get the preadjustment derivative

    angle += .1

    pendulum.angle = Math.sin(angle);

    currentangle_d = Math.cos(angle);  // Get current derivative

    // If signum of current and previous derivatives differ, we've passed a maximum
    if (Math.sign(lastangle_d) !== Math.sign(currentangle_d)) {
        console.log("pendulum is at its maximum")
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

If someone really wants to hack, `if (lastangle_d*currentangle_d < 0)` could do that too.

Comment: Technically, this always tells you you just *passed* the maximum, without distinguishing between whether the current `angle` or the last `angle` was closer, correct? That might be adequate, depending on the use case, it just doesn't match the OP's request to know when it's *closest*.